# Information regarding XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am initial stage of my XSLT but I couldn't find any information at google regarding XSLT. I just go through W3schools which looks like not up-to the mark with the concepts, guys suggest me some more websites or if you have any documents please share with me your suggestions are very important

Thanks

Comment: Tutorial:- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xslt/index.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Personally, when I'm learning a new language, I don't think there's anything to beat a good book. It's not so much because the printed medium is better than online; it's because a good book will be the product of a lot more thought and effort than anything I've ever found online. It takes 6 months to produce a good book, while a lot of tutorial web sites seem to have been cobbled together in a weekend with very little thought.

Most of the books on XSLT are now a little dated, but the concepts are still valid. It's hard to produce a recommendation without knowing, for example, how much experience you have with other languages, but Jeni Tennison (Beginning XSLT 2.0, APress) is very good at explaining the concepts in a well-thought-out order.

My own book is a very comprehensive reference (XSLT 2.0 / XPath 2.0 Programmers Reference, Wiley, 4th ed.), but probably not the best first introduction unless you're the kind of person who really wants to explore every nook and cranny of the language in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i hope these could help you,

http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/XSLT_Tutorial_-_Basics

https://nwalsh.com/docs/tutorials/extreme2006/plain.html

http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTutorial/Books/Output/contents.html

Good luck :)

Comment: I have a small question I was keep on digging the answer but not yet situation is

Comment: Sure Soji will be in touch with you if I have any quires with XSLT